# Make the flag count disappear after flags are viewed in chat

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, 10k-tools

Right now 10k users on any given site can see flags from chat.  The idea here, is that the 10k'ers will see the flags and then add their own to make the offensive content go away.

However, if a user views the flags and decides that they are not flag worthy, the notification stays in the chat window.  There seems to be no way to get the notification to go away, and thus you can't tell when new flags are added, or if you are still seeing the old ones.

I think that once the flags are seen, the blue flag count should go away from the chat window.

Some example flags that I don't feel deserve more flags:
[image: example flags]

Comment: On the other hand, if 1769 people downvote this we can get you under 10k, solving the problem once and for all

Comment: @Michael, yeah, that would solve the problem...for a little while.

Comment: This has been completed a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

This is really annoying, I've seen 5 flags on SO chat over the past week and only 1 of them was actually spam/offensive.

[Example](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/5?m=17786#17786) of what I mean:

> **dzen** [image]**:**  lmorning

How this can be considered spam or offensive in chat is beyond me.  However, the flag stays there until all the flags are cleared or enough flags are reached to remove the item.  In some cases, I've seen the number of flags increase - probably because some 10k users hope that the flag icon will go away quicker if they just flag it.

I'd much rather have some sort of flag debate - if a message is flagged as spam by someone else, let me say that it isn't spam or offensive and let my "deflag" cancel 1 point (but only a flagged message can receive a "deflag" point).  This way, I can still moderate flags effectively.

Comment: Agreed, I'm sick of seeing meaningless flags.

Answer (score 1):

The implication that seeing the page of flagged comments automatically means that I've evaluated them all is a little too hasty.

While there are going to be some users who are able to look at and distinguish between all of them, yes. But there are also going to be users who would prefer to be able to evaluate them one at a time.

To me it makes more sense that it is the # flags, rather than "unread flags".

Comment: Well, I think you should at least be able to dismiss the flags somehow.

Comment: currently it has the same behaviour as the flags on the regular sites. If they change that, it should be consistent across all of them.

Answer (score 1):

This would be fine, but we'll then need a way to go back to the flags if we realize we do want to go over them again (since the blue button will now be gone that links you there).