# How can I see flags from the chat?

Tags: support, chat, 10k-tools

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63125/10k-flag-powers-in-chat) mentions users with access to the 10k tools being able to see the chat flags. Where is the link to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there are any flags, you'll see a number on your avatar in the bottom left of the screen:

[image: flags and unicorns]

That number is a link to the flagged messages overview.

Comment: Does it mean "1 flag from this user", or "1 flag against this user" or "1 flag for the chat room in total"?

Comment: Interestingly, I reviewed a few in Charcoal, and I'm only at 9.2K.  I'm also privileged with Smokey, does that make a difference?